# Linear Algebra - Vector points

Tags: linear-algebra

So I am stuck on this question it states that:

if u and v are vectors below, find the vector w whose tail is at the point halfway from the tip of v to the tip of u and whose head is at the point halfway from the tip of u to the tip of u-v. Assume all vectors are in standard position.

u = [-2,1,-5]  v = [2,-2,-2]

I did the calculation and u - v = [-4, 3, -3]

But I'm not sure what the vector w is going to be.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The point halfway from the tip of v to the tip of u is

$$P=\frac{u+v}{2}=\left(0,-\frac12,-\frac72\right)$$

The point halfway from the tip of u to the tip of u-v is

$$Q=\frac{u+u-v}{2}=\left(-3,2,-4\right)$$

Thus

$$w=Q-P=\left(-3,\frac52,-\frac12\right)$$